# Apple Mail won't delete messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Lately I have problems deleting messages in Apple Mail (Mac OS 10.11).
I select one or multiple messages, hit delete key and get an error saying that these messages have already been "deleted" (moved to the trash folder in Mail): that's not true, the trash folder is empty and I'm stuck with the problem.

What should I do? I tried also to rebuilt Mail's mailbox with Onyx utility, but the problem persist.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are these external mailboxes (Hotmail, Yahoo, Google, etc) that you're connecting to or is this your me.com or icloud.com addresses (standard Apple email accounts)?

Comment: No, these are Mail mailboxes

Comment: I understand they're in Mail but what accounts are being used?  You have to add your accounts to Mail so it knows where your mail is located.  Also, are you using POP or IMAP to connect to your accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried rebuilding Mail mailboxes, re setting preferences and so on to no avail. Then rebuilt and repaired whole hard drive with DiskWarrior 5. So far no further problems. Perhaps a coincidence, perhaps a solution but I pass it on for what it is worth.